# wget and changing directory in a bash script

Tags: bash, wget

How do I change to a directory A, run `wget` in directory A, then change to another directory B, and run `wget` in directory B?

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd directory_A && wget --spider -i addresses.txt && cd ..;
cd directory_B && wget --spider -i addresses.txt && cd ..;
```

My code is failing at the end of the first `wget`. However, if I replace wget with some other command, like `touch` or `pwd`, the script works as intended.

Thanks.

Comment: so you need to debug `wget ..`?

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? If wget encounters a condition that makes it return a non-zero status then the trailing `cd` won't be executed.

Answer (score 6):

In general, it's a bad idea to try to keep track of directories and cd back to where you where.  Instead, just run in a subshell:

```
#!/bin/sh

( cd directory_A && wget ... )
( cd directory_B && wget ... )
```

The first wget will run from within directory_A, and regardless of what happens the script will remain in the current directory so that the relative path of directory_B is correct.

Comment: Another option is to use the directory stack: `pushd directoryA; wget; popd; pushd directory_B; wget; popd`. This is useful if you have code you can't put in a subshell (it sets variables used by code in the next directory, for example).

Comment: Note that `pushd` is a good solution, but is not portable (not all shells provide it).  You can also use `$OLDPWD` or `cd -` in shells that provide that functionality (most do).

Answer (score 0):

```
a && b
```

means: Only execute b if a was completed successfully. So, when `wget` fails, `cd ..` is not executed.

Maybe you want to do this?

```
 cd directory_A; wget --spider -i addresses.txt; cd ..;
 cd directory_B; wget --spider -i addresses.txt; cd ..;
```

If you want us to solve your `wget` problem, you should provide some error messages.

Comment: Thank you. It hadn't occurred to me that wget was failing. I even did wget --help and it worked, so that should have given me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd directory_A && wget --spider -i addresses.txt
cd ..
cd directory_B && wget --spider -i addresses.txt
cd ..
```

it won't stop after failing the first `wget ..` command